# How do I return value from inner function without creating chain of return?

Tags: node.js

```
function xyz() {
    function abc() {
        function haha() { 
            return 5;        
        }
         return haha();
    }
    return abc();   
}
console.log(xyz());
```

I get '5' in console. Thats ok. Its a simple code of larger problem where there is lots of nested functions. I dont want to return one after the other. Is there any way, I can return from any function and return it to original function caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
function xyz() {
    function abc() {
        return 5;
    }
    return abc()
}
console.log(xyz());
```

Comment: missing semicolon ;)

Comment: Sorry, initally I coudn't frame the question in a right way. Now, I have edited the question to what it should have been. Issue is also in chaining tons of returns. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a return the from abc function call

```
function xyz() {
    function abc() {
        return 5;
    }
    return abc();

}
console.log(xyz());
```

Or return an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
function xyz() {
  return (function abc() {
      return 5;
  })();

}

console.log(xyz())
```

Comment: Sorry, initally I coudn't frame the question in a right way. Now, I have edited the question to what it should have been. Issue is also in chaining tons of returns. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe you need call backs. I don't get the context of what you are trying to do but I'll just try.

```
function logTheAnswer (a) {
    console.log(a)
}

function add(a, b, cb) {
    cb(a + b)
}


add(1,2,logTheAnswer)
```

now you can nest the call backs indefinitely though try to keep it a minimum as you will experience call back hell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but your question is a bit confusing without a proper output representation. But you can use callback functions with which you can easily manage your nested calls and returns.

```
function myFunc3(a, b, callback3){
    callback3(a+b);
}
function myFunc2(a, b, c, callback2){
    myFunc3(a+c, b, function(result2){
        callback2(result2);
    })
}
function myFunc1(){
    myFunc2(a,b,c, function(result1){
        console.log(result1);
    })
}
```